# Running `npm ci` in AWS CodePipeline fails: "Cannot read property 'aws-cdk-lib' of undefined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I came across some strange behaviour when calling `npm ci` within an AWS CodePipeline.

The [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci) recommend using `npm ci` ("clean install") instead of `npm install` in automated environments.
The AWS CDK docs follow this recommendation in their [CDK pipelines example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html):

```
const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  synth: new pipelines.ShellStep('Synth', {
    ...
    commands: [
      'npm ci',
      'npm run build',
      'npx cdk synth',
    ],
  }),
});
```

When I tried this, however, my pipelines failed at the `npm ci` command with a strange error message:

```
[Container] 2022/12/14 16:00:37 Running command npm ci
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'aws-cdk-lib' of undefined
```

The package `aws-cdk-lib` was the first entry in my `package.json` dependencies. So it seems like CodeBuild was not able to parse my dependencies when installing via `npm ci`. Strangely, everything worked fine when I replaced `npm ci` with `npm install` ... but I wanted to find a way to make this work with `npm ci`.

Answer (score 8):

The reason that `npm ci` does not work is that CodeBuild uses an old version of npm. When I checked, the newest release of npm was 9.2.0 but CodeBuild was using 6.14.17.

Updating npm before running `npm ci` fixed the issue:

```
const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  synth: new pipelines.ShellStep('Synth', {
    ...
    // Update npm before running commands
    installCommands: ['npm i -g npm@latest'],
    commands: [
      'npm ci',
      'npm run build',
      'npx cdk synth',
    ],
  }),
});
```

A minimum working example of the issue and the fix can be found [here](https://github.com/estrehle/codebuild-npm-ci-bug).

Comment: I wanted to add that the pipeline must be recreated since it can't mutate its own build step if the build fails. Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: OH MY GOD. I wasted too many hours on this. Thank you!

Comment: @EricJiang I don't think this is true. I believe you can just go into the CodeBuild project for the CodePipeline and edit the `buildspec.yml` commands directly. Once you change it to get the pipeline working, the CodePipeline will self-mutate.

Comment: Sure that works too. I should have said the pipeline can't deploy its own fix via CDK/self-mutate.

Comment: I think this is now fixed by https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/24544

Comment: @EricJiang No, it's not. Still giving the same error.

Comment: Works for me using "aws-cdk-lib": "2.81.0"

Answer (score 1):

I had recently updated my `node` using `nvm` to v18 and this likely changed the lock version of the `package-lock.json` to one which is not compatible with the version of `npm` that is installed in CodeBuild.

The solution would have been (had I not worked around it another way) use `node` v16 to update my `package-lock.json` before committing and releasing.